# Compose VerticalPager with scrollable item in it causes laggy nested scroll

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-jetpack-compose

I can't accomplish smooth scroll behavior with pager and scrollable item inside it. Is there any way to make transition smooth, or disable it at all ?
I'm using 'androidx.compose.foundation:foundation:1.5.0-beta03' version

```
@Composable
fun BugSample(text:String) {
   val state = rememberPagerState() {
        15
    }
    Column {
        VerticalPager(state = state) { page ->
            Column {
                Box(
                    Modifier
                        .fillMaxWidth()
                        .fillMaxHeight(0.7f)
                        .background(Color.White)
                )
                Text(text = text, Modifier.verticalScroll(rememberScrollState()), color = Color.White)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Behavior]